# Replacement for Car Amplifier ( Rockford Fosgate Punch 60x2 )

Tags: audio

My very old amplifier, a Rockford Punch 60x2 (this is an old amp) was ruined.  It was underneath the seat of my car and my car got flooded a bit.

I need to buy a replacement, and just get my system working again.

The punch 60x2 says it has 30 Watt RMS into 4 OHMS.  Rockford Fosgate R150X2 looks like it could be an appropriate replacement but would prefer a recommendation or a confirmation.

I also need to be sure that I can just reattach all of the same connections used by the 60x2.